# Numbered references in bibliography

Tags: bibtex, apacite

I am using the `apacite` package for referencing.

The journal I am submitting an article to requests that all references are listed, numbered, each reference starting on a new line, without line breaks inside the references.

How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \bibliography{test.bib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using `\apacite` which donot support numbered bibliographies.
You can try by adding,

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
```

in your preamble.

Hope this helps.

Oh my bad!, `[numbers]{natbib}` is unsupported for `apacite` .bst. You can try the following, which places the references with proper indentation marks.

With response to the below mentioned comment. Add the following into your preamble. You need to skip `natbib`, as it is not supported for `apa` style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\setlength{\bibhang}{-1pt}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! As soon as I change to `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` I get a long list of error messages (undefined control sequence, missing = inserted for \ifnum, etc. ...

Comment: I used JabRef to make a sublibrary based on the .aux file, then exported as MS Office from JabRef, then selected all and applied bullets. It's not elegant, but hey.

Comment: See my recent edit.

Comment: I still get a long list of errors, but at least I get a pdf document that seems to be complete (without reference numbering though). So I apply my hack (see comment above) as this gives me the reference numbers.

Comment: Try to clean the auxillary files and recompile the main(.tex) file.